# To speed up the tapply function in R, or another function to convert data frame into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tapply

I need to convert a huge dataset into a matrix. The data structure likes the below data "x". When I use the function tapply to do it (see below), it cannot work due to memory limit for the huge dataset.
I am wondering if there is another way to do it. I tried for the R package dplyr, but didn't figure out how to do it. Any suggestion for that? Thanks so much.

```
x <- data.frame(c1=c("A","B","C","A","B","C"), c2=1:6, c3=c("sp1","sp2","sp2","sp2","sp3","sp4"))
y <- tapply(x$c2, list(x$c1, x$c3), sum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(x, names_from = c3, values_from = c2, 
                   values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)

#  c1      sp1   sp2   sp3   sp4
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A         1     4     0     0
#2 B         0     2     5     0
#3 C         0     3     0     6
```

`data.table` is usually faster in which case you can use -

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(x), c1~c3, value.var = 'c2', fun.aggregate = sum)
```

---

Output can also be represented in long format.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  group_by(c1, c3) %>%
  summarise(c2 = sum(c2)) %>%
  ungroup
```

and with `data.table` -

```
setDT(x)[, sum(c2), .(c1, c3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  x,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "c1",
  timevar = "c3"
)
```

gives

```
  c1 c2.sp1 c2.sp2 c2.sp3 c2.sp4
1  A      1      4     NA     NA
2  B     NA      2      5     NA
3  C     NA      3     NA      6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `xtabs` in `base R`

```
xtabs(c2 ~ c1 + c3, x)
#   c3
#c1  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
#  A   1   4   0   0
#  B   0   2   5   0
#  C   0   3   0   6
```